# How is the final variable System.out changing its reference?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

class SetOutExample
{
    public static void main(String...s)throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("abc123.txt");
        PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(fout);
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.setOut(ps);
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Here the output of `hi` is printed on a file `abc123.txt`. How does the `PrintStream`-type variable `out` which is final and has the reference to print on screen get modified and start pointing to file `abc123.txt`? How does `setOut` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on source code of `java.lang.System`:

```
public static void setOut(PrintStream out) {
    checkIO();
    setOut0(out);
}
```

The job is done by `setOut0(out)`:

```
private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);
```

This method is `native`. It can do whatever it wants including changing of value of `final` fields.

BTW theoretically it can be done using pure java as well. They could use wrapper `PrintStream` to initialize `System.out`. In this case `setOut()` could go to the wrapper and change object that it wraps.

Answer (score 2):

OK, notwithstanding the confusing English, it appears that the problem here is "how come `System.out`, which is supposedly `final` as per the Java sources, can be modified via `.setOut()`".

Well, "all bets are out" here; If you look at the `System`'s `.set{Out,In,Err}()` methods, at least in Oracle's JDK, you will see that ultimately they call these methods:

```
// emphases mine
private static **native** void setIn0(InputStream in);
private static **native** void setOut0(PrintStream out);
private static **native** void setErr0(PrintStream err);
```

Native code will do "whatever it wants" in order to achieve its goals; it won't care about such a "petty" thing that is "final" in the Java language. In this case, these methods have the special privilege of modifying std{in,out,err} under the scene without even the process running the JVM noticing.

Short story: magic. Long story: well, those methods work so just use them, and don't heed the `final`; it is only there so that *your code* cannot reassign `System.{out,in,err}` and you have to go through the dedicated methods instead.

---

Mind you, any calls to `.set{In,Out,Err}()` will first entail a check against the current security manager, if any; this means you can prevent these methods from acting at all if the need arises.